# Create a list from pairwise comparison

Tags: c#, linq

I perform a pairwise comparison on a number of objects and estimate the similarity

```
Item-1,Item-2,Similarity
11, 16, 0.9
11, 18, 0.5
11, 21, 0.9
12, 19, 0.8
12,22, 0.9
12, 24, 0.3
```

I wish to now create clusters based on a threshold, for example with a threshold of 0.8 would like to create lists as below:

```
{11,16, 21}
{12,19,22} 

with threshold > 0.8
```

Is there a way to do this in LINQ?  I found several ways of generating pairs from lists, however I need to do it in reverse.

Comment: But there is no similarity known between `16` and `21`. And furthermore what do you use as threshold? The minimum/sum/product/...

Comment: since 11 is common to both 16 & 21, they need to be clustered together. Not sure I get the 2nd part of the question

Comment: Well you could say the similarity of the first cluster is `0.72`: `s(11,16)*s(11,21)`. Some AI algorithms do this because of the *Naive Bayes assumption*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a collection of such pairs with the properties, `Item1`, `Item2`, and `Similarity` where the first two are integers and the second a double.

```
var threshold = 0.8f;
var sets = pairs.Where(p => p.Similarity > threshold)
                .GroupBy(p => p.Item1, p => p.Item2)
                .Select(g => new [] { g.Key }.Union(g));
```

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for. Thanks a ton. Been stuck on this for a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the requested groups using

`items.Where(i => i.Similarity >= .8).GroupBy(i => i.Item1)`

and then the list is `group.Key` + `group.Select(i => i.Item2)`